# Android: Is the Google secret API for location still valid

Tags: android, location, wifi, cellid

Is this link still valid:

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40524/1954.
Looks like there is a secret API for location. It does not seem to work now. I think this is  very old version because it does not say anything about the Google MAPS api key etc.
Can some one please confirm is this is still valid ?
Is it replaced with locationmanger.networkprovider code.

Thanks in advance for help on this.

Comment: Chances are if it's "secret" it was never *valid* for third party use in the first place.

Comment: Which part of the code mentioned in the article above are you referring to as "secret"? You mean the  www.google.com/glm/mmap, not?

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the  GLM MMap API (www.google.com/glm/mmap) as being secret:

As of May 31, it seems that somebody's still seems to be using it, see

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/mSKE7eQohNE

even though the original website that is linked to from your article above does not exist anymore under http://www.google.com/glm/mmap

But I would assume it's still working, even though inofficial and not sure about the license/legal issues that come with your question.

And `telephonyManager.getCellLocation()` is still a valid API in Android (at least it's still in the SDK never tried myself what value it returns though).

Comment: 1) My question is getting the latitude and longitude after getting the cellid, lac, mnc, mcc 2) Thro the telephone API i am getting the cell id, lac , mnc, mmc but not the exact location in terms of latitude and longitude. 3) Using opencell id database i am able to get the location of the cell id towers i am connected to but not my phones location. 4) I am trying to get my exact position of my phone using the google secret API 5) using location manager i am able to use network provider and get the location, but not thro this : http://www.googlecom/glm/mmap